# Why is using a variable in elif giving an error if it is declared in if?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

```
opt = int(input('enter'))
if opt ==1:
    m = int(input('enter'))
    print(m)
if opt == 2:
    print(m)
```

The error is like this

File "", line 6, in 
NameError: name 'm' is not defined

Comment: If `opt` is 2, what would you expect to be printed?

Comment: `m` is never defined if `opt==2`

Comment: 1. You don't have `elif`. 2. When the program goes into `opt == 2`, it means `opt` is `2`, which in turns means `opt` cannot be `1`. This means that the program didn't see inside the first `if` statement. So `m` is not defined.

Comment: Can't i use a variable declared inside if statement to use it in another elif or else ?

Comment: In this case you can't, because that line that defines m _will not get executed_ if opt is 2.

Comment: @j1-lee thank you for the comment. I understood.

Comment: @itsmekali321 *python doesn't have variable declarations*, unless you mean something like `global` and `nonlocal`, or perhaps type annotations.

Answer (score 1):

If opt is equal to two, then Python runs the code "print(m)", but m was only defined if opt is equal to one.

```
opt = int(input('enter'))
m = int(input('enter'))
if opt ==1:
    print(m)
elif opt == 2:
    print(m)
```

Comment: No problem! Actually, you don't need to use the if-else statements at all since you are printing the same thing in both ;)